# Image disappear when the email is sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, send-email

I have this code that includes the picture of a product.

```
<!--[if mso | IE]><td style=vertical-align:middle;width:150px><![endif]-->
<div class="mj-column-per-25 outlook-group-fix"style=font-size:0;text-align:center;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:25%>
    <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 role=presentation style=vertical-align:middle width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td style=font-size:0;padding:5px;word-break:break-word align=center>
                <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 role=presentation style=border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0>
                    <tr>
                        <td style=width:100px>
                            <img height=auto src="%%=v(@imageURL)=%%" style=border:0;display:block;outline:0;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px width=100>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso | IE]></td><![endif]-->
```

The issue is when I do the preview the image is displayed but when I do a real sent it disappears, the @imageURL variable always include a valid image URL.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the Concat function?

Comment: to be able to include ampscript inside the code (the value of @ImageUrl), is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use inline AMPscript to output the `@ImageURL` value?  Removing the double-quotes to make the concat function work is likely the issue:

```
<!--[if mso | IE]>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;width:150px">
<![endif]-->
    <div class="mj-column-per-25 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0;text-align:center;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:25%">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:middle" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:0;padding:5px;word-break:break-word" align="center">
                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:100px">
                                <img src="%%=v(@imageURL)=%%" style="border:0;display:block;outline:0;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px" width="100">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
</td>
<![endif]-->
```

Also appears that you have some missing `td` and `tr` tags.  It might be helpful to re-indent everything to ensure it's structured as you intended.

**Reference**

- [Function Index](https://ampscript.guide/function-index)
- [v](https://ampscript.guide/v)

Comment: Thanks Adam, I already fixed the code but still same issue...

Comment: Please update your question with the fixed code.

Comment: It is already updated

Comment: does the image show when you simply output `<img height="auto" src="%%=v(@imageURL)=%%" style="border:0;display:block;outline:0;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px" width="100">`?

Comment: And why are you not using quotes around your tag attribute values?